# How to add "int argc and char *argv[]" to my main function and impliment into my code?

Tags: c, function, input, arguments

I am working on creating an uppercase function. I want to implement argc and argv arguments in to my code but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code;

Main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "upperc.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[] = "HellO2 world3!";

    printf("%s \n", s);
    printf("%s \n", uppercase(s));

    return 0;
}
```

upper.c:

```
/*
Parsing the string, then making the letters to uppercase.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "upperc.h"

char * uppercase(char *s) {
    for(char *p = s; *p; ++p) {
        if ('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z')
            *p = *p & ~' ';
    }

    return s;
}
```

upper.h:

```
#ifndef UPPERC_H_INCLUDED
#define UPPERC_H_INCLUDED

char * uppercase(char *s);

#endif // UPPERC_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: If you call it like `myprog "hello world"` then you can use `uppercase(argv[1])`. Note the quotes on the command line.

Comment: Instead of `*p = *p & ~' '` use `*p=toupper(*p)` or `*p = *p & ~32` to indicate it is about the 6th bit, and not about a space.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify how exactly you plan to call your program. Do you want to call it as `myprog "hello world"`, i.e. wrap the text in quotes in case it contains spaces, or do you also want to call it like `myprog hello world and whatever` without quotes?

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will modify it! I agree but usually people don't like to seeing magic number 32 a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this looks like some kind of homework, I don't give a full answer.

`argc` is the number of arguments **including** the program name that was executed. That means `argc` is 1 if no arguments were specified, 2 if one argument was specified etc.

Don't pass `argv[1]` unconditionally to your `uppercase` function. This would be undefined behavior if `argc` is 1 or even 0. (see below for details)

Depending on your requirements, you should check `argc` and process either only `argv[1]` if available, which would be the first argument, or process `argv[1]`, `argv[2]` ... in a loop as necessary.

---

Additional details  (for experts, because my original wording was not exact):

If your program is called in a normal way, the value of `argc` should be at least 1 and `argv[0]` will be the program name. The value of `argv[argc]` is a `NULL` pointer. Of course you can access the pointer value in this case, but you cannot dereference it, i.e. you cannot access a value where the pointer would be pointing to.

It is possible to call your program in a way that results in an `argc` value 0. In this case `argv[0]` will be a `NULL` pointer, and the array element `argv[1]` (and all following it) will be undefined.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer It's really helpful. It's not a homework it's self though tests, I am working on it thank you for all advice.